# Deployed a war file in AWS but only accepts HTTP GET; HTTP POST returns 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, jax-rs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deployed my war file in AWS using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, only HTTP GET is processed. HTTP POST is rejected with 405 Error - Method Not Allowed.

The war file being deployed is basically JAX-RS web services using Jersey framework. When deploying it locally, everything works normally.

I am using all resources under AWS Free Tier - EC2, S3, RDS (MySql) and AWS AMI Linux with Tomcat.

Is there any configuration in AWS that I need to set to allow HTTP POST?

I already tried modifying Tomcat web.xml to set readOnly to false but still did not fix the problem.

Is this something to do with Security such as described in IAM - roles and permissions?

I really wish that the solution requires changing only config files and not modifying source code.

Thank you in advance for your answer :)

Comment: Does your resource have the @Post annotation?

Comment: Yes, it has @POST annotation.

Comment: @ludwinbarbin were you able to fix it? I am currently uploading war from Jersey - it would be helpful if you can post the solution.